# Bluetooth dongle or Windows will not detect earbuds

Tags: windows, bluetooth, dongle, earbuds

I've searched and I've been unable to find any answers, so I'm praying someone can help me here.

```
OS: Windows 10
Bluetooth Dongle: Eveo 5.2 USB
Earbuds: Creative Outlier Pro
```

Problem: windows will not detect my bluetooth earbuds off of the dongle (or at all).

What I have tried:

Updating windows. Updating windows drivers. Uninstalling and using default drivers installed with dongle. Installing Intel/Realtek/Com/3rd party drivers. Enabling services: BTAGService, bthserv, BluetoothUserService_6c749 (both auto and manual). Installing windows default bluetooth drivers, SFC /SCANNOW, bluetooth troubleshooter, different USB ports (2/3.0), a different dongle, and variations of them all.

Results: Windows detects the dongle but not the earbuds. When drivers are installed, two Generic Bluetooth devices show up in the device manager, and two show up in the windows settings > devices. If they're both enabled (in the device manager) one of the bluetooth radios displays "driver error" in the settings until I disable it in the device manager. I have disabled them both, one by one, and have left them both on to the same result--no earbud detection. No matter what I try, Windows will not detect the earbuds when searching/parring. The earbuds are detectable by multiple phones (iphone/android, etc), each on old and new OSs.

Anomaly: using a virtual machine with the exact same build of my OS actually detects the earbuds under the same conditions. In other words, when the vm is allowed to use my usb dongle, it detects it the same way my main os does, and when using the parring in settings it actually detects my earbuds, using my machine as a proxy. All the settings and drivers are the same. Trying this on another computer, separate from mine, the same problem persists.

Current device settings:

[image: Current device settings]

Any help to figure this out would be great. I am lost and have no idea what else I can do. I even tried to install cab files off of windows update to no avail. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Can you ask the manufacturer if Windows 10 supports your earbuds?  They may not be compatible.

Comment: They are supported, however, there is a catch-22. If you want to install their application, they need to be detected first and running to make use of it.